# Clean way to filter paths array

Tags: javascript

How to filter the following array

```
[ '/pageA/pageAA.html',
  '/pageB.html',
  '/pageC.html',
  '/pageC/',
  '/pageC/pageW/pageC.html',
  '/' ]
```

to get

```
[ '/pageA/pageAA.html',
  '/pageB.html',
  '/pageC/pageW/pageC.html' ]
```

The rules are:

- Path doesn't end with `/`
- Path shouldn't be similar to another path which end with `/` ex: `'/pageC/'` and `'/pageC.html'` are similar

I have done the following but it's not clean maybe there is a cleaner way with regex or something like that

```js
const routes = ['/pageA/pageAA.html',
  '/pageB.html',
  '/pageC.html',
  '/pageC/',
  '/pageC/pageW/pageC.html',
  '/'
]

const filterRoutes = routes => {
  var unWontedRoutes = []
  for (let i = 0; i < routes.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < routes.length; j++) {
      if (Math.abs(routes[i].length - routes[j].length) == 4) {
        var a = routes[i].length < routes[j].length ? routes[j] : routes[i]
        var b = routes[i].length > routes[j].length ? routes[j] : routes[i]
        if (a.replace(b.slice(0, b.length - 1), '') === '.html') {
          unWontedRoutes.push(a)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return unWontedRoutes
}

const unWontedRoutes = filterRoutes(routes)
const newRoutes = routes.filter(route => (!(unWontedRoutes.indexOf(route) > -1) && !route.endsWith('/')))

console.log(newRoutes)
```

Comment: Why `/pageC.html` is not in output ?

Comment: @CodeManiac because `'/pageC/'` exist

Comment: _Path shouldn't be similar to another path which end with `/`_ - Please define _similar_ in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `filter()` and `some()`

```js
const routes = ['/pageA/pageAA.html',
  '/pageB.html',
  '/pageC.html',
  '/pageC/',
  '/pageC/pageW/pageC.html',
  '/'
]


const res = routes.filter(x => !x.endsWith('/') && !routes.some(a => a.endsWith('/') && x.split('.')[0] === a.replace(/\/$/,'')))

console.log(res)
```